# $E[|W_tW_s|]$ for a standard Brownian motion $W_t$

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion. I want to calculate $E[|W_tW_s|]$. I already know that $E[W_tW_s]=\min\{s,t\}$, but what about the absolute value?

Comment: Hint: $(W_t,W_s)\sim N(0,\begin{bmatrix} t \,\,\min \{s,t\}\ \\ \min \{s,t\}\,\, s\ \end{bmatrix} ) $. Integrate $|xy|$ w.r.t. the joint density.